# How do I get unwanted miscellaneous figures out of a string in postgresql

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, data-cleaning

I have a utm value column, 'source_medium' with values that appears in my dataset as:

```
0.9899.com/(none)
0.9239.com/(referral)
0.77569.com/(cpc)
0.9899.com/(organic) 
0.54966/(email)
```

I want to get the (none) or (referral) or (organic) part separately as the case may be but every time I try I get this figure in the resulting column :

```
[...] (none)
```

I have tried different approaches to remove the [...] like:

```
substring(split_part(source_medium,'/',2) from 1 for 9) as utm_medium
```

The above only works for the '0.9899' part when I use the function like this:

```
split_part(source_medium,'/',1) as utm_source,
```

It doesn't work well when I try to separate the [...] from the utm_source (none). I'm using PostgreSQL

Comment: see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=770984c0d19953121917a5ef74d93b48) for some (working) solutions.  (some explanation added)

Comment: @Luuk , your Comment looks like a useful *Answer to me

Answer (score 1):

Use `regexp_replace`:

```
select regexp_replace(source_medium, '.*\((.*)\).*', '\1')
```

Match the whole string, capturing your target, replacing with the capture.

Comment: Or: `select substring('0.9899.com/(none)' from '.*\((.*)\).*');`

Comment: Hi @Bohemian . I actually revised the question based on the values in the source_medium column. There are other values in the ( ) like (email), (referral), (organic), etc. I apologize for the oversight.

Comment: @JoshuaSmart-Olufemi so what's the problem? My query will find anything between brackets.

Answer (score 1):

I updated the [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1cd9ebd5dadbfd7156f4b9f3d9bb828a) (from the one given in the comments)

This shows the second example given is not correct in all situations.

One example (for all see the dbfiddle):

```
select 
   source_medium,
   replace(replace(split_part(source_medium,'/',2),'(',''),')','') as utm_medium
from tbl;
```

output:

| source_medium | utm_medium |
| --- | --- |
| 0.9899.com/(none) | none |
| 0.9239.com/(referral) | referral |
| 0.77569.com/(cpc) | cpc |
| 0.9899.com/(organic) | organic |
| 0.54966/(email) | email |